# Any GUI based simple tool that can make my JARs of android un-decompilable?

Tags: android, java

I want to build a library project into JAR specifically to run only on Androids 2.3 and above. I do not have any resources to add in the library. Its just plain code.

I tried ProGuard and obfuscated the jar, and tried couple of combinations via its GUI, but the output jar is always unusable in the main project. The class names get obfuscated and the APK compiler always throws errors of class not found types.

If I do not obfuscate the class names, it still obfuscated the methods in it and again the APK compiler throws errors of method not found.

The JAR file gets created properly though.

However, I tried decompiling the obfuscated file via a JAR decompiler I downloaded, and it was still able get all the code generated, just with different method names and class names. The code was pretty much readable.

Hence, I am looking for a GUI based tool to make the JARs in such a way that the decompiling is impossible (or very very hard to decompile), like a straight forward binary file. However, I tried searching a lot and had no luck.

I find pro guard very confusing, since I've never dealt with it and there are a lot of compiler based terminology in the options, of whose effects I am not sure.

Can any one share me some info of any such robust tool which doesn't make the programmer delve into the core level setup of the obfuscator itself ?

Comment: Impossible to accomplish.